# How to use osmbonuspack with osmdroid?

Tags: android, osmdroid, openstreetmap

I discover osmbonuspack but the API information and the documentation in the wiki is very low.

http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/

I think that this library is very interesting to upgrade osmdroid but I can not learn to use it.

Has been used by someone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a look again in the wiki, I just completed with a tutorial, here:

http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_1

Hope it will help!

To go further, there is also a sample application in the source repository: OSMBonusPackDemo, and the javadoc. 
And don't hesitate to ask questions in the issues of the project.

Comment: I try to do points three and four as show in code but when touch marker this don't show the bubble. The program throws an exception. I posted the question with the code in the project's wiki also.

http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_1

Comment: The exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.osmdroid.views.MapView$LayoutParam.<init>

Comment: I've accomplished find the bug. It's in ExtendedOverlayItem when obtain the package's name. Your code obtain the class package instead of the app's package.

Comment: osmbonuspack has moved from http://code.google.com/ to https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack

Comment: @MKergall you have developed an excellent library . I would like to know that is it possible to get speed limit using osmbonuspack as I'm developing app which needs speed limit allowed for current location of driver.